# ALSA: How to configure an (virtual) audio device for each channel?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, mono, dj

I would like to play different sound/music of the left and right speaker/headphone. I understand that left and right speaker are called channel 1 and 2 in ALSA.
The DJ software I'm using (mixxx) does not allow me to select the channels separately in the configuration. Therefore I'd like to create additional sound devices which I can pick in the DJ software. These devices should then be either connected to channel 1 or 2 of the sound device.

I spend quite some time reading the docs about alsa and asoundrc files. It sounds that it should be possible but I have not idea how.

The soundcard is a: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210

Comment: AFAIK Mixxx does not show virtual device defined in `.asoundrc`.

Comment: It shows devices that are defined like that:
`code`
pcm.ens1371 {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
}
`code`

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be Mixxx version 1.11.0
The feature is only available from 2.0.